# Push Notifications aren't sent - Parse SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm creating and sending push notifications with [Parse](http://parse.com) SDK, however I'm finding that none of my notifications are arriving. Am I doing something wrong? I've set up the App ID and Provisioning Profile correctly because I can send test notifications from Parse.com Dashboard

```
        // Create new Push Notifications
        PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
        [pushQuery whereKey:@"user" equalTo:otherUser];

        NSString *pushNotificationMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ added you",[[PFUser currentUser] username]];

        // Send push notification to query
        PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
        [push setMessage:pushNotificationMessage];
        NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"added you",@"Alert", nil];
        [push setData:dict];
        [push setQuery:pushQuery];
        [push sendPushInBackground];
```

Comment: Have you checked the query to make sure it's definitely returning results?  If Yes, are the pushes showing up on Parse's server?

Comment: Hi...Plz can you discribe what is user in this line...
[pushQuery whereKey:@"user" equalTo:otherUser];

Answer (score 0):

Check 'Push Notification' section in your parse after sending push notification from your device.

Check for subscribers,if subscribers are ZERO it means:

1. Either query is wrong, not returning users.
2. User's devices are not registered.
3. For user's creation and device registration you are using custom
   class. It is required to register user with built in parse Users
   class.

Hope these things will help you. I faced same problems.